# How do I convert a *char to _TCHAR?

Tags: windows, visual-c++

This is what I tried but it didn't do anything.

```
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_COMPOSITE, optarg, -1, localdir, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the start of the function add: "USES_CONVERSION;"
and it allows you to use the macros: "A2T", "T2A" ... so you need A2T
enjoy

Comment: I'm getting this errorerror C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'LPWSTR' to '_TCHAR [260]'
          There are no conversions to array types, although there are conversions to references or pointers to arrays

Comment: type your code exactly..
basically, if your chars are wchars and you want to convert it to tchars, then use W2T.

Comment: Sorry about there. Here is the code again - http://www.nomorepasting.com/getpaste.php?pasteid=35009

Comment: you want to copy string.. so you can use _stprintf(localdir,_T("%s"),A2T(optarg)). try it.. tell me if it works

Comment: Yes, this works but I get a warning - warning C4996: '_swprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _swprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdio.h(544) : see declaration of '_swprintf'

Comment: Tried it with _stprintf_s and there are no warnings and it works the same as _stprintf, so I guess this is what I should be using, right?

Comment: yup. the difference is of course the num of chars limit.
glad i could help

Comment: the relevant include is 
#include <atlconv.h>

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use many way:
1. wstreamstring << szYourCharStar;

1. _bstr_t bstr = szYourCharStar;

Those way can minumize your effort of resource management, if you use other way, you might need to free up the resource.

For instance:

_com_util::Convert_To_WCHAR ?? forget the name.